# upload.single() unresolved and req.file is undefined

Tags: android, node.js

this is the server code on webstorm.upload.single gives unresolved error i have installed the multer module but still it gives error and  even if i dont use upload.single req.files give undefined when console.log

```
var express = require('express');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var multer = require('multer');

**var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });**


var app = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 8080;
var config = require("./config");
var requests = require("./model")(config);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/uploadimage',**upload.single('img')**,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.file);


});
```

this is the client code

```
public class filterpic extends AppCompatActivity {

File filePath;
String photoPath;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filter_page);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.appbar0);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    **photoPath = extras.getString("photoPath");
    filePath = getFileStreamPath(photoPath);**

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(filePath));
    ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagebyte);
    imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

public void upload(View view){
    new HttpUpload(this,String.valueOf(filePath)).execute();


}
```

}

```
 public class HttpUpload extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

 private Context context;
 private String imgPath;
 int serverResponseCode = 0;


 public HttpUpload(Context context, String imgPath) {
super();
this.context = context;
this.imgPath = imgPath;
}


@Override
protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {

String upLoadServerUri = "http://192.168.10.182:8080/uploadimage";


HttpURLConnection conn = null;
DataOutputStream dos = null;
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary = "*****";
int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
File sourceFile = new File(imgPath);
if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {
    Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File Does not exist");
    return 0;
}
try { // open a URL connection to the Servlet
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    Log.i("uploadFile", "" + fileInputStream);
    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",imgPath );
    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""+ imgPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); // create a buffer of  maximum size

    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    // read file and write it into form...
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {
        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)
    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

    //close the streams //
    fileInputStream.close();
    dos.flush();
    dos.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

    ex.printStackTrace();

    Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
} catch (Exception e) {

    e.printStackTrace();

    Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
}
return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your node server is looking for a file field with the name `img` but your Java code is using `uploaded_file`. Change one or the other and it should work (provided the Java client is formatting the request properly).

Comment: upload.single() gives an unresolved error webstorm doesnt recognize it as a method even though multer module is installed

Comment: and what do you mean  by (provided the Java client is formatting the request properly)

Comment: RE: "unresolved error", make sure you have the latest version of `multer` installed just in case. I don't use Webstorm, so I'm not sure how well it's supposed to work with node modules. RE: Java client request formatting, I was referring to the Java code that is manually crafting the multipart request (stitching the parts and boundaries together, setting various headers, etc. manually).

Comment: can u recommend a better ide for nodejs which one do u use

Comment: I can't help you with that as I don't use IDEs.

Comment: upload.single error was removed but when i run the code req.file doesnt show anything and the client gives a 500 internal server error HTTP Response is : Internal Server Error: 500 and on the server side i just get this POST /uploadimage 500 22370.699 ms - 1515

Comment: sorry abt the previous comment i mistyped uploaded_file it works now

Answer (score 2):

Answering after the storm but was googling this question and it was one of the first results. Installing type definitions for multer solve the unresolved error in Webstorm.

```
npm install --save @types/multer
```